# Get Top 1 from UNION Subquery

Tags: t-sql

I want to identify which of a number of tables contains the earliest record. To do this I thought I could just say:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM
( 
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table1' as TableName FROM Table1 
  UNION
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table2' as TableName FROM Table2
)
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

In SQL Server 2008R2 it tells me theres a syntax error near 'ORDER'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give your sub-query an alias:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM
( 
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table1' as TableName FROM Table1 
  UNION
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table2' as TableName FROM Table2
) q
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't define an alias on the subquery,

```
SELECT TOP 1 TableName 
FROM
     ( 
         SELECT CreateDate, 'Table1' as TableName FROM Table1 
         UNION
         SELECT CreateDate, 'Table2' as TableName FROM Table2
     ) aliasName     -- <<== ADD HERE
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

`ALIAS` is needed in order for the subquery to be identified.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM
( 
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table1' as TableName FROM Table1 
  UNION
  SELECT CreateDate, 'Table2' as TableName FROM Table2
) RandomName
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the others (so far) have the correct answer (you need an alias for your derived table), but I also suggest that rather than UNIONing and sorting all of the CreateDate and TableName values, you get just the minimum CreateDate from each table, and cultivate the habit of using UNION ALL when you don't need to eliminate duplicates.  So, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM
( 
  SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS CreateDate, 'Table1' as TableName FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS CreateDate, 'Table2' as TableName FROM Table2
) x
ORDER BY CreateDate ASC
```